# Is there any MQTT client specifically for Xamarin forms?

Tags: .net, xamarin, mqtt

I have searched a lot about MQTT client for xamarin forms, but I am unable to get a bit of information about it. When I tried to install the MQTT client in the Nuget package of .net framework it shows an error saying "The .Net framework does not support the version of MQTT client".